# Deeply shuffling a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random, shuffle

Im looking for a function or an algorithm to shuffle a dataframe/matrix of floats in R, not by rows or columns only but rather a complete deep randomization of the values.

I tried the function sample() to shuffle the rows first and then the columns but the elements of the same row will end up in the same row just in a different order, im looking more for a complete shuffling.

df =     t1 t2 t3 t3 
      g1  1   4   7   0  
     g2  8   7   2   9  
     g3  4   6   8   1

should result in

df =     t1 t2 t3 t3 
      g1  8   2   4   1  
      g2  2   1   8   6  
      g3  7   9   7   0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `unlist`, I believe you can still use `sample`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  row.names = c("g1", "g2", "g3"),
  t1 = c(1, 8, 4),
  t2 = c(4, 7, 6),
  t3 = c(7, 2, 8),
  t4 = c(0, 9, 1)
)
df

shuffle <- sample(unlist(df), size = length(unlist(df)))
shuffled_matrix <- matrix(shuffle, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df))
df_shuffled <- data.frame(shuffled_matrix)
row.names(df_shuffled) <- row.names(df)
colnames(df_shuffled) <- colnames(df)
df_shuffled
```